# "TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'" occur while using multiprocessing.Pool()

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, typeerror

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x,y):
    return x*y

with Pool(4) as p:
    print(p.map(f,[2,2,2],[3,4,5]))
```

The message goes like:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-25-e9ce49d0ccbf> in <module>
      1 p = multiprocess.pool.Pool()
      2 # result = p.map(for_multical,[N]*n,[k]*n)
----> 3 print(p.map(f,[2,2,2],[3,4,5]))
      4 p.close()
      5 p.join()

D:\software\python\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    362         in a list that is returned.
    363         '''
--> 364         return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
    365 
    366     def starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):

D:\software\python\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py in
_map_async(self, func, iterable, mapper, chunksize, callback, error_callback)
    483 
    484         task_batches = Pool._get_tasks(func, iterable, chunksize)
--> 485         result = MapResult(self, chunksize, len(iterable), callback,
    486                            error_callback=error_callback)
    487         self._taskqueue.put(

D:\software\python\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py in
__init__(self, pool, chunksize, length, callback, error_callback)
    795         self._value = [None] * length
    796         self._chunksize = chunksize
--> 797         if chunksize <= 0:
    798             self._number_left = 0
    799             self._event.set()

TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

`self._chunksize = chunksize`,it seems the `chunksize` missassigned. How could this happen? How to fix this?

The same problem goes with package 'multiprocess'.

Comment: The optional third argument to `map()` has to be an integer, not a list.

Answer (score 1):

The [Pool.map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) differs from the regular `map()` in that it accepts only one iterable. The solution is to use [.starmap()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) instead, but it expects the iterables in other format, see the linked docs.

```
print(p.starmap(f, zip([2,2,2],[3,4,5]) ))
```